# Remove HasMany Association in HQL

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I have the following association in my classes:

```
class A {
}

class B {

 static hasMany = [
    objects: A
  ]
}
```

I want to use an HQL query to remove a the associations from all Bs.

Here is what I tried:

```
B.executeUpdate("update B b set b.objects.id=NULL")
```

but the former did not work.

**How can I Remove HasMany Association fin HQL?**

Comment: So to clarify, since you don't have a `belongsTo` in `A` you have a join table with a name like `b_a` right? And after clearing out all of the A instances from the B instances' collections, you still want all of the A instances to be there and detached without an owning B? Or delete the A instances?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith yes I have no ``belongsTo``and yes I have the join table. Just remove the A instances from B without deleting them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to retain all of the A and B instances, but just detach them, the net effect however you do this is that the join table will be emptied. The most efficient way of doing that is with SQL:

```
delete from b_a
```

I can't find any way to do that via HQL since the join table isn't mapped - it's managed by Hibernate for you (just like in a many-to-many), but you don't have any direct access to it. Typically you would work with instances in the Groovy/Java code, e.g. to delete one `B` instance's `A`s you would do this:

```
B b = ...
b.objects.clear()
b.save()
```

which generates SQL similar to

```
delete from b_a where b.id=?
```

But doing this one at a time would obviously be inefficient, and I don't see any bulk options either on the Grails or Hibernate side. So I'd just run that SQL query, and the easiest way to work with SQL is `groovy.sql.Sql`:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MyService {

   def dataSource

   void detachAllAsFromBs() {
       Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
       int rowCount = sql.executeUpdate('delete from b_a')
       log.debug "removed $rowCount entries from b_a"
   }
}
```

You can ignore the return value from `sql.executeUpdate` - the number of rows deleted isn't particularly interesting:

```
void detachAllAsFromBs() {
    new Sql(dataSource).executeUpdate 'delete from b_a'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the association rather than going all the way down to the id. Try:

```
B.executeUpdate("update B b set b.objects=NULL")
```

Since that didn't work in the comments (I think it is the correct syntax): Are you sure the relationship between B and A should be static? The static in that spot seems wrong but without a stack trace or more details it is tough to tell.

Comment: Any more detail available than "does not work?" Are you getting an exception? What version of hibernate.

Comment: A null collection doesn't make sense (they're empty or have elements) - how do you imagine your HQL getting converted to SQL?

Comment: Of course it is static as defined here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html

Comment: I mean logically, in an OO/ORM sense.